# vlcj black screen when playing video

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

I am having a bit of trouble with nested JPanels playing a video. I have an AVPlayer class extend JPanel which plays up to 4 videos simultaneously. Each video is played inside its own canvas which is inside its own JPanel. All the panels are then put into the AVPlayer panel. But when I try to play the videos all I get is a black square.

I'm not sure what the actual problem in my bigger program is but I think I can solve it if I can get the videos to play using the second bit of code below. Can someone tell me why the first bit of code is properly able to display all the videos, but the second one is not.

Code that works:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    AVPlayer player = new AVPlayer();   
    frame.getContentPane().add(player);
    frame.revalidate();
    String[] path = {"(ei)ga_00.mp4", "ei-utsu(ru)_00.mp4", "video.mp4"};
    player.playVideo(path);
```

Code that shows one small black square

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    AVPlayer player = new AVPlayer();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();        
    panel.add(player);

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.revalidate();
    String[] path = {"(ei)ga_00.mp4", "ei-utsu(ru)_00.mp4", "video.mp4"};
    player.playVideo(path);
```

Comment: Change `JPanel panel = new JPanel(); ` to `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` to `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());`

Your `AVPlayer` should also override the `getPreferredSize` method of `JPanel` and return the "preferred size" of the component, this way the layout managers have some hope of actually been able to do there jobs

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Beware that vlcj's primary video surface is a heavy weight component and mixing them on light weight containers can generate some undesirable effects

Comment: I overrode the getPreferredSize method for AVPlayer. The AVPlayer class itself has 4 panels with a borderlayout and 4 canvases added to each of those panels. I changed the AVPlayer layout to GridLayout and now everything works fine. It's too late to prevent mixing of components. I didn't know that was a thing until I was well into my program. This was the last problem I was facing and since it's resolved, I'm going to be wrapping up this little project. I'll the light and heavy components in mind for next time though. Thanks a lot for the help. I had been at this problem for several hours.

Comment: Mixing heavyweight and lightweight components is no big deal, frankly. Sure, you need to know about potential problems, but in practice it hardly matters.

Comment: @caprica Your practice obviously differs from mine, I've had no end of wired z-order issues and painting issues when ever they are mixed, even though it's suppose to have been fixed